# Can't insert values into the created table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm working on Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I've created a table `[WORKER]` in the database `[ORG]`. Now I'm trying to insert some values into the `[WORKER]` table in each designated column, but it won't allow me to do so. Does anyone know?

```
INSERT INTO WORKER (WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) 
VALUES (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR');
```

[image: Query and Columns]

[image: VARCHAR DATE PROBLEM]

Comment: Its because of the identity on your primary key. You cant specify a value, just dont put any worker_ID and it will generate one automatically

Comment: You are using an incorrect `datetime` format. Check that [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and convert using the correct format.

Comment: According to datetime documentation, the format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. It also says that you should use Datetime2 instead of datetime because it is more portable type and it aligns with SQL standard

Comment: now you can check and try edited code

Answer (score 0):

**You can not insert any value in identity column**

Its increase automatically when you check ISIDENTITY property YES

Try This

```
INSERT INTO worker 
        (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, Department) 
        VALUES ('Monika', 'Arora', 100000, (convert(datetime,'14-02-20 09:00:00',5)),'HR')
```

5 here is the style for Italian dates. Well, not just Italians, but that's the culture it's attributed to in

Comment: I tried yours, but it gives me "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." I have inserted the problem in the question.

Comment: @user234568 you can not insert datetime datatype to nvarchar you need to convert in date formate

Comment: 5 here is the style for Italian dates. Well, not just Italians, but that's the culture it's attributed to in

Answer (score 0):

You have set Worker_Id as identity column. So sql will not allow you to insert value in this column. Its value will be automatically created when you insert data in other columns.

If you want to insert your own value in identity column then before insertion you need to allow identity insert in table like following query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT WORKER ON;

INSERT INTO WORKER(WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) 
VALUES (1, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT WORKER Off;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the the solution will help since the whole error message is not displayed!

But hopefully it should work. The error message is coming because you are trying to insert values in identity column i.e. `WORKER_ID`, identity column values are incremented automatically in sql.

You can try setting the IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF

Final Query

```
INSERT INTO WORKER (WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) 
VALUES (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT WORKER OFF
```

Hope it helps, please let me know if it works.

Comment: I added the error in the question above. Now, it's giving me "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."..What can I do about this?

Comment: I think if you remove the time 09.00.00 from the string it should work fine, and maybe add another column for the time field.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want identity column also you must should have use identity_insert off**

try:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT WORKER ON;
INSERT INTO WORKER(WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) 
VALUES (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, (convert(datetime,'14-02-20 09:00:00',5)), 'HR');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT WORKER Off;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with date format '2019-10-09 00:21:14.480'